# Search bar able to search with commas - mySQL/php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to edit my search bar so that users can search for values separated by commas. It calls on mySQL db. Can anyone help? I'm sure this must be obvious but I'm new. Thank you!

search page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
    <p><strong>Search:</strong></p>
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <p><input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/></p>
    <p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1"> Medalist</p>

<p><strong>Medal:</strong>
<select name="medal">
<option disabled selected></option>
<option value="1">Medal 1</option>
<option value="2">Medal 2</option>
<option value="3">Medal 3</option>

</select>
</p>
<p><strong>State:</strong>
<select name="state">
<option disabled selected></option>
<option value="1">AL</option>
<option value="2">AK</option>
<option value="3">AZ</option>
<option value="4">AR</option>

</select>
</p>
<p><strong>Year:</strong>
<select name="year">
<option disabled selected></option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</optio>
</select>
</p>
<p><strong>Topic:</strong>
<select name="field">
<option disabled selected></option>
<option value="1">Field 1</option>
<option value="2">Field 2</option>
<option value="3">Field 3</option>

</select>
</p>
```

Search results page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:admin.php");
}

 $search = $_POST['search'];
        $type    = (isset($_POST['type'])   ? "AND medalist = '1'" : "");
        $medal  = (isset($_POST['medal']) ? "AND medal = '{$_POST['medal']}'" : "");
        $state  = (isset($_POST['state']) ? "AND state = '{$_POST['state']}'" : "");
        $year  = (isset($_POST['year']) ? "AND year = '{$_POST['year']}'" : "");
        $field  = (isset($_POST['field']) ? "AND field = '{$_POST['field']}'" : "");


 $search_sqli = "
            SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE (
                    first_name      LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  last_name       LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  first_name2     LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  last_name2      LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  last_name2      LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  city            LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  agency          LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  subcomponent    LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  team_name       LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  achievement     LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  profile         LIKE '%{$search}%'
                OR  year            LIKE '%{$search}%'
            )
            {$type}
            {$medal}
            {$state}
            {$year}
            {$field}
        ";

$search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
     <p>Search:</p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
   <br />
    <p><strong>Search Results:</strong></p>
  <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
     do  {
         ?>
    <p><ul>
    <li><a href="view_profile.php?profile=<?php echo urlencode($search_rs["id"]); ?>"><?php echo $search_rs['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['first_name2']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name2']; ?></a></li></ul></p>     

<?php } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));

  } else {
      echo "No results found";
  }
  ?>
  <br />    
  <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="search.php" role="button">Back to search</a></p>
    </div></div>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: If you really have a searchbox with values separated by commas you should be using `explode()` somewhere, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
$searchArray = explode(',', $_POST['search']);
```

and then foreach through that array running the search query for each item, append the results of each query and then display the complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explode the search and then use those values?

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$myNewSearch = explode(",",$search);
$searchLen = count($myNewSearch);
for($i = 0; $i < $searchLen; $i++){
 Select * from profiles WHERE (
 first_name      LIKE '%{$myNewSearch[$i]}%'
 ... 
}
```

Its a little long, but it would get you everything typed in without the comma.